# Windows Certificate Service Authority templates to issues

Tags: windows, certificate, templates

I have the problem that I cannot issue self-made certificate templates in the certificate authority, i.e. in the certificate authority, right click to certificate templates and select *certificate template to issue*. My templates do not appear.

Situation (with some chronological changes):

- 1 forest; 2 domains (A.local and B.local)
- 1 main-ca (root-ca) und 2 sub-ca (sub-ca1 and sub-ca2)
- Main-ca: installed on domain-controller of A.local
- Sub-ca1: installed on domain-controller of B.local
- Sub-ca2: issued only certificate for sub-ca2: sub-ca is a linux-based ca.
- Upgraded from Win2008R2 to Win2019 -> exported CA from dc_A_2008R to dc_A_2019
- sub-ca1 was removed from domain controller and B.local was removed  only A.local remaining
- Replication to all DCs of domain A
- Revoked all certificated issued to domain B.local and also revoked certificate for sub-ca1
- Root-ca is working for computer certificates (enrolled by GPO)
- Root-ca is working for web-based (using browser) certificate requests like webservers.
- Root-ca is working for user certificates

**Remark**: After the movement of the certificate authority to the new DCdc_a_2019 I also updated the Certificate Revocation List Distribution Point.

So, after googling I found the following issues which could be the reason for the problem:

- Wait for replication such that all templates are replicated to all DCs -> this is done
- B.local is cleanly removed from the schema, PDC …
- Remove sub-ca1 in manually in AD sites and services (this I also did)

**Errors in Event log**:

- The request was for a certificate template that is not supported by the Active Directory Certificate Services policy (0x80094800).
- The Online Responder Service could not locate a signing certificate for configuration.

### **An additional remark:** I cannot add the OSCP-Responder as template neither.

Any ideas how to solve. How to debug?

Comment: What are the security ACE's permissions on the template?

Comment: The security permissions are "Read", "Write", "Register" for Domain-Admins and Oragnization-Admins. Furthermore, the dc_A_2019 has the permission to "read" and "register".

Actually, when I moved the CA, I first moved it and uninstalled it afterwards from the dc_A_2008R. When both domains were existing, the problem I described above did not appear. Therefore, I think it is not due to permissions. 
But thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Moreover, the "Authenticated Users" group has the "read", "write" and "register" permissions.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I found the problem and solution here: https://securitymusings.com/article/1733/cant-create-a-new-certificate-template-to-issue

In case the link will not work in future:

1. Open the ADSIEdit.msc
2. Right click on **ADSI Editor** - **Connect**
3. Under **connection point** select **Configuration** and **OK**
4. Navigate to **CN=Configuration | CN=Services | CN=Public Key Services | CN=Enrollment Services**
5. Right click on the Attribute and select **properties**
6. Select the **flags** - if it is **2** then update it to **10**
7. Replicate between the DCs (use Active Directory Sites for manual replication)
8. Restart the Certificate Authority (Right click - Tasks - **Stop** - **Start**)